# How to keep design docs in sync across per-user databases

Tags: validation, couchdb

I am building an app, for example, todoapp.

Features:

1. Offline-first (couchdb + pouchdb)
2. Multi-user

CouchDB options: require_valid_user, couch_peruser.

Ok, each user has a private database. But how can I validate docs on post/put?

design/validate_doc_update must be in every user db (userdb-{hex}).

How can I place it there and update it sometimes all at once? Sync? Third db/replicate? How can I replicate to all userdbs?

Answer (score 1):

You have three basic options, which are all quite similar:

1. Set up continuous replications between a prototype database and each user's database.  For large numbers of users, and low frequency of updates, this could amount to a lot of overhead for little gain.
2. Trigger a one-off replication between a prototype database and each user's database, every time an update occurs. This requires you to know when an update occurs in your application, and to manually handle any replication failures that may occur. This overhead may be pretty small in simple scenarios.
3. Have your application update the design docs every time they change, for each user database. This is sort of a manual sync option.

Which option you choose is really up to you, and is a matter of trade-offs.

If you would ever desire the option to update only a subset of users (say a beta testing group), then option 2 or 3 are going to be your best bets.